# What happens to old questions when a tag is deleted?

Tags: discussion, tag-deletion

Mods of sites sometimes delete tags.

When they do, what happens to old questions that had the tag? Is the tag automatically removed from all such questions?

What if a question only had that one tag? Is it left without tags?

Comment: Moderators cannot delete tags outright - only developers can do that. And we generally avoid doing it when there are questions with only that one tag because it will leave them untagged with low visibility. Generally a tag being "deleted" involves the community working through them all to retag them.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this backwards, tags are deleted automatically around 24 hours after they have been removed from all  questions.

What happens is that moderators or users remove the tag from all questions, not that they delete the tag. That way we can't end up with questions that have no tags.

Comment: Ah, I see :) Misunderstood.